# Software for drawing schematic diagrams

Tags: open-source, drawing

Is there is any software that can be helpful in drawing professional diagrams such as circuit diagrams and systems diagrams for engineering reports?

For example this diagram

[image: schematic circuit diagram]

Comment: I don't think there is anything particularly *scientific* about this diagram, is there? As such, the title of the question may evoke wrong ideas.

Comment: Dia?  https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [TinyCAD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinycad/)

> TinyCAD is a program for drawing electrical circuit diagrams commonly
>   known as schematic drawings. It supports standard and custom symbol
>   libraries. It supports PCB layout programs with several netlist
>   formats and can also produce SPICE simulation netlists. It is also
>   often used to draw one-line diagrams, block diagrams, and presentation
>   drawings.
>
> Features
>
> - Flat or Hierarchical Schematic Entry
> - Many popular PCB Layout compatible netlist formats
> - Convenient support for embedding graphical images in drawings

[image]